# iOS Swift Push Segue Catch Trigger Back Button Function

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

What function gets triggered when a user hits the back button on a push page?  I need to set some properties before going back to the previous page.  ViewWillDisapper is not what I'm looking for

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use either `viewWillDisappear` or `viewDidDisappear` to monitor a user going back on a pushed page (assuming you mean this is inside a navigation controller).

Answer (score 0):

Just like when you call your instance method of UINavigationController to "pushViewController:(BOOL)animated:" guess what method is called to POP a view controller? try something like 
[self.navigationBar.backButton //Not sure if this is what its called addTarget:self selector:@selector(popViewController)]

and fill in the rest of the method with UIEventTouchUpInside so when the user presses the back button on navigation bar it will jump into you're overrided function.

Make your View inherit UINavigationController protocols and then overide popViewController method.

I suggest looking at UINavigationController class reference if that didn't answer your question.